# If $A, B \in [m,n] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are sets of measure zero, then is $AB = \{ab | a \in A, b \in B\}$ measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

If $A, B \in [m,n]$, where $[m,n] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are sets of measure zero, then is $AB = \{ab \; | \; a \in A, b \in B\}$ measure zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $C$ is the Cantor set and $A=B=\{e^{x}:x\in C\}$ then $A$ and $B$ have measure $0$ but $AB$ contains all numbers of the form $e^{x+y}$ with $x,y \in C$. Since $C+C=[0,2]$ it follows that $AB$ does not have measure $0$. [I have used the following facts: $e^{x}$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ and any absolutely continuous function maps sets of measure $0$ to sets of measure $0$. Hence $A$ and $B$ have measure $0$].  Note also that $AB$ contains the entire interval $[e^{0},e^{2}]$ so it has positive measure.

Comment: I followed your argument, but I was thinking about the following, but I'm not able to figure out where went wrong: Let $E = A \cup B$. Then $AB \subseteq E^2$. We know $E$ has measure zero. Since the function $f(x) = x^2$ is Lipschitz, it maps sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero, so $E^2$ has measure zero, which means its subset $AB$ is also measure zero.

Comment: $AB$ is the image of $C+C=[0,1]$ under the absolutely continuous function $e^x$. We know that every absolutely continuous function sends a set of measure zero to a set of measure zero. But can we say that it sends a set of positive measure to a set of positive measure?

Comment: @Anupam No you cannot say that any absolutely continuous function maps a set of positive measure to a set of positive measure. (An obvious counterexample is given by a constant function). But in my argument $AB$ contains all the numbers  from $e^{0}$ to $e^{2}$ so it has positive measure.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I got your argument. May be $C+C=[0,2]$ and $AB$ contains all elements from $e^0$ to $e^4$.

Comment: @RalphXu You are getting confused with notations. It is not true that $AB$ is contained in the image of $E$ under $f(x)=x^{2}$. The image consists of the points $t^{2}$, with $t \in E$ not products of any two elements of $E$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right. Thank you. Just not to be confused, you meant $C+C=[0,2]$ rather than $[0,1]$, right?

Comment: @RalphXu Yes. $C+C=[0,2]$.